# Basicauth setup on Elasticsearch 6 dot release

Tags: elasticsearch, basic-authentication, elasticsearch-6

I am trying to test few plugins related to user access for test user (custom access based doc filtering) on ES and I need to have basic auth to validate it. Is there a user manual for setting up basic auth  setup at elasticsearch  (6 dot release) at server end. Any information will be great help.

Comment: What plugins are you testing?  I have never heard of a plugin that restricts user access to documents, without including basic auth...
Or are you looking for a plugin that has basic auth and user restrictions?

Comment: I wrote a plugin that does custom access check on search results object and I wanted to use basic auth user (for testing my logic) to be mapped to search result access rights. To do so I needed to setup basic auth for my test cases.